# ¿Porque no se muestran bien las card de bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Quiero mostrar lo que son unas recetas en la pagina y me gusto la manera de usar las `cards` pero al momento de implementarla algunos textos se quedan fuera, no se porque pasa esto, alguien tiene una idea?
[image: Imagen con el error]

Aquí les dejo la imagen de como el texto sale, por debajo y no quiero que pase eso, necesito que todas las `cards` queden dentro del fondo blanco.

```html
<section id="main-content">
      <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
        <div class="row mt">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row content-panel">
              <div class="col-md-12 centered">
                <br>
                <h2><i class="fas fa-running"></i> Resetas saludables</h2>
                <br>
                <p><strong>Para poder alcanzar tus meta es muy importante incorporar una actividad física en tu rutina.
                    Recomendamos hacer 30 minutos de ejercicio, 3 a 5 días por semana.</strong></p>
              </div>
              <!-- /col-md-6 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /row -->
          </div>
          <!-- /col-lg-12 -->
          <div class="col-lg-12 mt text-center">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card col-md-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="img/plato.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card col-md-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="img/plato.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card col-md-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="img/plato.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /col-lg-12 -->
          </div>
          <!-- /row -->
        </div>
      </section>
      <!-- /wrapper -->
    </section>
```

Y bueno aquí les dejo el código que utilizo.

Comment: En primer lugar, el código que subes muestra elementos tipo `col` huérfanos. En la documentación de la [grilla](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#how-it-works) de Bootstrap se establece lo siguiente: *Las filas (`rows`) son el envoltorio para las columnas (`cols`)..., En un diseño de grilla, el contenido va dentro de las columnas(`cols`) y sólo las columnas (`cols`) pueden ser elementos hijo inmediatos de las filas (`row`)*. Entonces, tus elementos iniciales `col-lg-12` están huérfanos y tu elemento `card-deck` está en un lugar no apropiado entre una fila y sus columnas. Saludos

Comment: Acabo de modificar el codigo que muestro para mostrar la seccion completa, estara mal?

Comment: Probé el código que publicaste y el texto se ve bien, no sobresale de las cards, seguramente tiene algún css aplicado

Comment: Si al final cambie el tamaño en el css y me funciono bien